# How to get the link of next page when the next page loads itself while scrolling down

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from e-commerce site but I am able to scrape data from one page. So I tried to paginate through pages but the problem here is there is no next page button in the current page and next page loads itself when I scroll down to bottom of current page. I am using BeautifulSoup in Python to scrape data.

scraping page url :
http://www.shopclues.com/mobiles-smartphones.html

When I did inspect the page before scrolling down to end I found something like:

```
<div class="load_more">
   <a id="moreProduct" catid="1431" class="btn btn_effect" href="javascript:void(0);">Load 875 More Products</a>
</div>
```

so I am assuming that this `<div>` tag is the reason for loading next page.
If yes, please provide me an answer to how to get link to next page.
If no, then please do inspect the URL I have provided and provide me an answer for the same.

Comment: Open the network tab in the developer tools (the thing that opens when you inspect) and watch what happens when you scroll down.

Comment: The page uses javascript to fetch extra content when you scroll down. If you use the browser's development tools, you can inspect the specific urls that contains the extra content. You might be able to just use those urls directly to scrape data. However, sometimes web sites might try to restrict access to crawlers.

Comment: how can I do this by my python code.

Comment: i mean i can not open and fetch link from network tab in developer tool from my code.

Comment: Either get "/ajaxCall/moreProducts?" with `urllib` / `requests` or use `selenium`

Comment: I will try with /ajaxCall/moreProducts?

Comment: There's probably no trivial way to get those urls with only python. They are presumably generated with client side javascript, so you would need to either run that javascript or reverse engineer it by inspecting the urls and the javascript code. In this case, only two parameters vary. `start` and `page`. `page` is an integer and `start` is `page * 36`.

Comment: start is not page*36 its (page-1)*36